# How to make a smart offset in excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement, numbers, offset

I have two columns - one is with project number, another one is with sub-numbers (included in project). 
What I would like to do is to create a "smart offset" - so if there is a project number, I don't want to see sub-number. I want to see sub numbers in rows below, etc.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfYwt.png)

[image]

What I have now is following:
=IF(A14=A13,"",A15)
=IF(E15<>"","",IF(E14<>"",B14,B15))

However, it doesn't work perfectly - it keeps missing the milestone (sub-project) on a row with the project (initiative) number.

I have attached the picture, because it's hard to explain.

I'm fine with adding extra columns if that is going to help.

thank you for help,
Marek

Comment: Use a pivot table!

Comment: thanks, but I'd prefer to avoid this... however if there is no better solution, than I'm going with a pivot. thank you!

Comment: Why are you avoiding a pivot table? This is exactly what they are good for

Comment: thank you for suggestion. I have a gantt chart with a lot of data (15-20 columns). All the data is vlookuped based on Initiative or Milestone.

Comment: @MarekRe I'd create a subroutine or function in VBA then. I bet someone can come up with a way to do this with just worksheet functions, but oh my goodness it'll likely be a big mess. If VBA is okay, then I could write you up something.

Comment: Yes, please! Let's see what we can have. thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a PivotTable to accomplish this very easily:

[image]

Comment: thank you - but I'd like to see cell B3 empty, and the first milestone should be in B4, etc. Pivot table is not the perfect solution, because I have a gantt chart connected to this data as well as 20 other columns - it's a table.

Comment: Okay, I don't think I'll be able to help you then, but hopefully someone else will be able to. Have you considered creating this gantt chart with a more flexible tool like R? https://stats.andrewheiss.com/misc/gantt.html

Answer (score 0):

I started playing with a VBA, only thing that I have to change is that every time the VBA is inserting a row each "i" value has to be increased by 1. So, if VBA inserted one row it's gonna be i+1 and i+2, if VBA inserted two rows its gonna be i+2 and lower i+3, etc... any ideas how to get to this point?

```
Sub test()

Worksheets(2).Activate

lastrow = Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 3 To lastrow

    If Cells(i, 8) <> "" Then
    Range(Cells(i + 1, 8), Cells(i + 1, 9)).Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Cells(i + 1, 9).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
    Else
    Cells(i + 1, 9).Value = Cells(i, 2).Value
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a VBA solution. It currently requires that you convert your table into an official excel "Table", which you can do by highlighting your data table, going to the Insert ribbon and selecting "Table". The advantage of this is that this code will work even if you were to move the table around in the worksheet.

I called my columns "initiative" and "milestone", and that's relevant in line 8 of the code. These columns have to be next to each other for this code to work. You'll have to change it to match your situation. You will also likely want to change the value of the "startCell" variable in line 10.

```
Public Sub CreateInitiativeListForGnatt()
    Dim tbl As ListObject 'The table object in your worksheet.
    Dim projCols As Range 'The initiative and milestone columns in the table.
    Dim projDict As Object 'The dictionary object we'll use to store key-values of initiative-[milestone1, milestone2, etc]
    Dim startCell As Range

    Set tbl = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    Set projCols = Range(tbl & "[[initiative]:[milestone]]")
    Set projDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set startCell = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D3") 'The first cell of the location where you want the list to be created.

    For Each r In projCols.Rows
        Call AddMilestoneToDictionary(projDict, r.Cells(1).Value, r.Cells(2).Value)
    Next

    Call writeInitiativeListToWorksheet(projDict, startCell)
End Sub

Private Sub AddMilestoneToDictionary(ByRef projDict, initiativeNumber As Variant, milestoneNumber As Variant)
    If projDict.Exists(initiativeNumber) Then
        projDict(initiativeNumber).Add milestoneNumber
    Else
        Set milestones = New Collection
        milestones.Add (milestoneNumber)
        projDict.Add initiativeNumber, milestones
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub writeInitiativeListToWorksheet(ByVal projDict, startCell As Range)
    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim currentRow As Integer, initCol As Integer, mileCol As Integer

    Set wrkSht = startCell.Worksheet
    currentRow = startCell.Row
    initCol = startCell.Column
    mileCol = startCell.Column + 1

    For Each initiative In projDict.Keys
        wrkSht.Cells(currentRow, initCol).Value = initiative
        currentRow = currentRow + 1
        For Each milestone In projDict(initiative)
            wrkSht.Cells(currentRow, mileCol).Value = milestone
            currentRow = currentRow + 1
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```